# Retrieve value from attribute in HTML tag in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a large string containing a custom HTML tag (xxx). The tag also has two attributes.

How would I retrieve the value of the two attributes and then place the tag and its content with a new string derived from those two attributes?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you want to retrieve it? In the code behind?

If your tag is runat="server", you can do:

```
mytag.Attributes["nameofmyattribute"]
```

Comment: It will be retrieved from the code behind but the tag isn't part of the page it is inside a string containing other HTML elements. I just need to find my custom tag and get the attributes from it.

Comment: So you have a string in the code behind containing a long HTML code, and you need to find your tag in that string?

Comment: That is correct yes, then retrieve the attribute values from that tag.

Comment: I don't get your problem... If is that just look for the substring of your tag... Sample: If you want some <span> tag , search for the occurrences of substring <span  ....

Comment: webforms almost died. What will be the similar case if it is not webform code behind and it is a asp.net mvc controller code?

Answer (score 1):

If its in string then you should consider using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
However it may be overkill so show us some sample string... maybe only some RegEx can do it.

Comment: Ok, well the string will contain roughly a paragraph of text, with an indefinite number (generally 1-12) of tags in the following format: <template category="x" field="y">text</template>. I will then pass x and y to a function which will return a string to replace the text inside the template tag (including the template tag) with.